# How add custom view to layout?

Tags: java, android, layout, view

I have a custom view

```
  public GraphView(Context context, float[] values, String title, String[]horlabels,  String[] verlabels, boolean type, int color) {
    super(context);
    if (values == null)
        this.values = new float[0];
    else
        this.values = values;
    if (title == null)
        title = "";
    else
        this.title = title;
    if (horlabels == null)
        this.horlabels = new String[0];
    else
        this.horlabels = horlabels;
    if (verlabels == null)
        this.verlabels = new String[0];
    else
        this.verlabels = verlabels;
    this.type = type;
    paint = new Paint();
    this.color = color;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float border = 20;
    float horstart = border * 2;
    float height = getHeight();
    float width = getWidth() - 1;
    float max = getMax();
    float min = getMin();
    float diff = max - min;
    float graphheight = height - (2 * border);
    float graphwidth = width - (2 * border);

    paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
    int vers = verlabels.length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < verlabels.length; i++) {
        paint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        float y = ((graphheight / vers) * i) + border;
        canvas.drawLine(horstart, y, width, y, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawText(verlabels[i], 0, y, paint);
    }
    int hors = horlabels.length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < horlabels.length; i++) {
        paint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        float x = ((graphwidth / hors) * i) + horstart;
        canvas.drawLine(x, height - border, x, border, paint);
        paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        if (i==horlabels.length-1)
            paint.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        if (i==0)
                paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawText(horlabels[i], x, height - 4, paint);
    }

    paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    canvas.drawText(title, (graphwidth / 2) + horstart, border - 4, paint);

    if (max != min) {
        paint.setColor(color);
        if (type == BAR) {
            float datalength = values.length;
            float colwidth = (width - (2 * border)) / datalength;
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                float val = values[i] - min;
                float rat = val / diff;
                float h = graphheight * rat;
                canvas.drawRect((i * colwidth) + horstart, (border - h) + graphheight, ((i * colwidth) + horstart) + (colwidth - 1), height - (border - 1), paint);
            }
        } else {
            float datalength = values.length;
            float colwidth = (width - (2 * border)) / datalength;
            float halfcol = colwidth / 2;
            float lasth = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                float val = values[i] - min;
                float rat = val / diff;
                float h = graphheight * rat;
                if (i > 0)
                    canvas.drawLine(((i - 1) * colwidth) + (horstart + 1) + halfcol, (border - lasth) + graphheight, (i * colwidth) + (horstart + 1) + halfcol, (border - h) + graphheight, paint);
                lasth = h;
            }
        }
    }
}

private float getMax() {
    float largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        if (values[i] > largest)
            largest = values[i];
    return largest;
}

private float getMin() {
    float smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        if (values[i] < smallest)
            smallest = values[i];
    return smallest;
}
```

and when i call 
            setContentView(graphView);
it's work good, but when i call

```
            diagramRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)switcher.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.diagramRelativeLayout);
            diagramRelativeLayout.addView(graphView);
```

it's don't work.

```
 Error:07-12 11:07:38.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30488): java.lang.RuntimeException:  Unable to resume activity {com.meters.src/com.meters.src.Main_Activity}:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

RelativeLayout contained in `ViewFlipper`. How i can add my view to this layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it, I just made xml with one layout, and added a reference to it in **diagramRelativeLayout**:

**my xml:**

```
  <RelativeLayout
  android:id = "@+id/diagramRelativeLayout"
  android:background="@layout/button_style"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
  android:layout_marginTop = "10sp"
  android:layout_marginLeft = "5sp"
  android:layout_marginRight = "5sp"
  android:layout_marginBottom = "10sp"
  android:gravity="center"> 
    <include android:id="@+id/graph" layout="@layout/graph"/>  
  </RelativeLayout>
```

**My java:**

```
graphLayout = (RelativeLayout)switcher.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.graph);
graphLayout.addView(graphView);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to add your view using code, you can do it in xml like any android view : 
in your case just add the following code in xml where you wan't your view

```
<com.your.package.GraphView android:id="@+id/myGraphView" />
```

Then in your activity you can retrieve it using

```
GraphView myGV = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.myGraphView);
```

Comment: 07-12 15:15:59.133: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31020): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.meters.src/com.meters.src.Main_Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #136: Error inflating class com.meters.src.GraphView

Answer (score 0):

A view can only have a single parent. The view that you are adding (I am guessing re-using ie. graphView) is already part of another view hierarchy. If you really want to reuse it (I would suggest you probably dont) then you have to detach it from its parent in its existing view hierarchy.

Comment: Check out you have already added this graphView somewhere else than  diagramRelativeLayout.addView(graphView);

Comment: I initialize it only in oncreate ()`graphView = new GraphView(context, values, "Weekly Usage (kW)",horlabels, verlabels, GraphView.BAR, Color.RED);`

Comment: This method, which returns the child of ViewFlipper.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line of code like as follows,

```
diagramRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)switcher.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.diagramRelativeLayout);

diagramRelativeLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();  // <-- Add this and try

diagramRelativeLayout.addView(graphView);
```